# Did I damage this shower valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I'm in the process of installing fixtures for a shower and realized yesterday that I had made a mistake and needed to expand the opening around the single control valve. It's a Moen with an insertable cartridge.

I removed some tile with a reciprocating saw and drill and am sure I didn't hit the valve at all.

However, now today I attempted to turn the water back on and—while in the off position—the valve now drips fairly steadily.

1. Did I likely damage the valve in the process of removing tile? Possibly through the vibrations of the saw/drill?
2. What steps can/should I take to repair this? The surrounding plumbing is in perfect condition, the valve is just leaky.

Thank you!

Comment: Moen's customer support is outstanding. I would call them and have them help you diagnose it: (800) 289-6636

Comment: I'll second that.

Comment: Moen sent me a new cartridge for free for my out-of-warranty shower valve without even verifying my warranty details. They _really_ care about their reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the leak at the faucet or the cartridge (handle)?
If the leak is at the faucet you may have shaken the seats loose or broke gunk in the pipe loose that got into the seats.
Both involve turning off the water and pulling the cartridge and looking for damage or debris.
If the leak is at the handle you may have cracked the plastic pivot / seal. With a new faucet they may replace it as long as there are no drill holes or gouges.

Comment: The leak is at the faucet. The pipes are brand new so I'll check the cartridge for any sign of damage. Thank you!